# Change Lottie Web speed, direction, etc before autoplay kicks in?

Tags: javascript, web-frontend, lottie

I've set up my Lottie animation using `let myAnimation = lottie.loadAnimation`. I need it to have the `autoplay` attribute set to true.
I want to change the speed to *2x*. I can do this using `myAnimation.setSpeed(2)`.
How can I guarantee this speed change *before* the autoplay kicks in (which is supposed to happen right after the component loads).
Is there anything I can do besides manually `stop()`, configure, and then `start()`?